# How to create non-overlapping popup in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use openlayers version 6.4.3.

I used wfs to add features to the map.

```
var wfsLayer = new ol.layer.VectorImage({
       source: ...,
       visible: true,
       renderMode: "image",
       renderBuffer: 150,
       zIndex: 1,
}); 
map.addLayer(wfsLayer);
```

I need to display a popup window over certain features of the added layer.

Popup windows are created for each feature coordinate, and must not overlap each other.

[image: example image]

Is there any way to make this possible?